# Two actions with one form

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to have a form submit to two different pages with one button press. Currently I am trying to submit the pages to two hidden iframes, but the second action doesnt seem to be working when I submit my form. Here is the edited version of what I am trying

```
<script language="javascript">
<!--
function OnButton1()
{
    document.Form1.action = "test1.php"    // First target
    document.Form1.target = "iframe1";    // Open in a iframe
    document.Form1.submit();        // Submit the page
    document.Form1.action = "test2.php"    // Second target
    document.Form1.target = "iframe2";    // Open in a iframe
    document.Form1.submit();        // Submit the page


}
-->
</script>


Submit Button
<input name="submit" src="test.png" type="image" id="submit" style="width: 238px; height: 92px; margin-top: 5px;" value="Submit" onclick="OnButton1();" />
```

iframes

```
<div style="visibility:hidden">
<iframe NAME="iframe1" WIDTH="40" HEIGHT="40"></iframe>
<iframe NAME="iframe2" WIDTH="40" HEIGHT="40"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: I dont think 2 forms could be submitted at once !! However you can use AJAX POST to submit the first and on success submit the 2nd !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot submit 2 forms in the same time.
I think that you must change your strategy to manage your case.

Pascal

Answer (score 0):

try this once

In javascript add this function

```
   submitForms = function()
   {
          document.getElementById("formID1").submit();
          document.getElementById("formID2").submit();
   }
```

now single form has to get 2 id's here is it

```
    <form id="formID1" target="iframe1">
    </form><iframe name="iframe1" style="display:none"></iframe>
    <form id="formID2" target="iframe2">
    </form><iframe name="iframe1" style="display:none"></iframe>
     <input type="button" value="Click Me!" onclick="submitForms()" />
```

Check this URL For DEMO
http://plungjan.name/test/duosubmit.html

Answer (score 0):

Change your input type to button.I think this will fix your problem. Instead of using iframe you can go with [ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/AJAX). If you are familiar jQuery [this](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) would help you.

Answer (score 0):

Since your form is submitted, your script does not executes further. Try submitting the form to second action on load of first iframe.

```
window.iframe2.onload = function(){
    document.Form1.action = "test2.php"    // Second target
    document.Form1.target = "iframe2";    // Open in a iframe
    document.Form1.submit();  
}
```

You'll need to have some kind of condition to prevent the form on load of window for the very first time.